# FocusIn bubbles on MainPage when focusing in iframe [TestCafe]

Tags: testcafe

#### Edit: This is bug so I [submitted an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7473)

I have a container div that has iframe child. container div has tabindex="-1" and is listening on focusin event.

### What is your Scenario?

The test simulates clicking on button inside iframe. iframe is a child of 'container-div'.

```html
<button>random button</button>
<div class="container-div" tabindex="-1">
 <iframe id="iframe" /> <!--- with button el inside -->
</div>
```

```js
containerDiv.addEventListener('focusin', () => console.log('focusin fired'))
```

```js
test("Dont fire focusin event", async (t) => {
  await t
    .switchToIframe(`.container-div #iframe`)
    .click("button");
  await t.switchToMainWindow();
  const { error, log } = await t.getBrowserConsoleMessages();
  log.forEach((log) => console.log(log));
  await t.debug();
});
```

### What is the Current behavior?

Focusin event fires, `"focusin fired"` is logged to the console

### What is the Expected behavior?

Focusin event doesn't bubble to main page when iframe is focused in non-test browsers. So focusin event shouldn't fire on 'container-div' element.

#### Environment details

"testcafe": "^2.2.0"

node v18.12.1

```js
let os = require("os");

const path = "tests";
module.exports = {
  skipJsErrors: false,
  hostname: os.hostname(),
  browsers: ["chrome"],
  src: [
    `${path}/iframes.ts`,
  ],
  speed: 1,
  current: 1,

};
```

Comment: I managed to reproduce the issue. You are right, the `focusin` event isn't raised without TestCafe and is raised with it. Please create a bug issue here: [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml)

Comment: @Aleksey Thanks for the response, I created this https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/7473 issue a while ago and forgot to update this post